# Having an issue inserting more than 1 row from a CSV into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv, sql-insert

I currently have been able to add one row of data from a CSV into the database but I am unable to add the next row and the next row.

I am simply asking why is it that only one row is being inserted into the database and is their a fix which would make all rows start inserting into the database?

Code Below:

```
include('config.php');

$file = "test.csv";
$separator = ",";
$length = 0; // size of the longest line(!), 0 = no limit
$fields = array('title', 'firstName', 'secondName', 'emailAddress', 'houseNumber', 'mobileNumber', 'address1', 'address2', 'address3', 'address4', 'postcode'); // use it as a white list

$handle = fopen($file, "r");

$header = array_flip(fgetcsv($handle, $length, $separator));

$values = array();

$i = 1;
while(($csvData = fgetcsv($handle, $length, $separator)) !== false){
echo $i." - You have inserted another row of data into the database.<br>";
    foreach ($fields as $field){ // put all values in an array in correct order
        $values[] = $csvData[$header[$field]];
    }
mysql_query("INSERT INTO csv (" . implode(',', array_keys($header)) . ") VALUES ('" . implode("','", $values) . "')"); 
 $i++;
}

fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Echo out your SQL queries and try to run them in the database. You should also be checking the return value of mysql_query, too, and logging any that don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using $header to map the values into $fields order so your insert should have the  fields in $fields order instead of $header order.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO csv (" . implode(',', $fields) . ") VALUES ('" . implode("','", $values) . "')");
```

also it would be a good idea to sanitize the data to make sure it is properly escaped.

```
$values = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $values);
```

before your mysql_query call should do it.

Also you are not re initializing  $values with each iteration so when inserting row 2 you get fields for row 1 + row 2.

so after you open your while statement do

```
$values = array();
```

to reinitialize it.

Comment: What you just said is wrong I believe, and it doesn't work at all now!

Comment: I must have misunderstood what your code is doing then... I was reading it as $fields being the desired order and $header being the order it appears in the csv file, your for loop appears to be reforming the record in values to conform to the order specified in $fields so I thought the order of the fields in the insert statement should match.

Comment: It probably will work just to add the `$values = array();` line as the first line in the while statement if the header column order matches the fields order.